# Trouble printing/writing text to using the correct formatting

Tags: ruby

i am new to Ruby and working on a project to take in text from a file, convert the text to  braille format, and then put the braille text into a new file.

Right now I am able to read the text, convert the entire string to an array. Then using a hash of English characters to braille, I am able to run map and replace the elements of the array with their braille equivalent.

I am having trouble interacting with the new array of Braille characters due to formatting issues.

```
starting_message = ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"]
braille_converted_message = [
 "0.\n00\n..",
 "0.\n.0\n..",
 "0.\n0.\n0.",
 "0.\n0.\n0.",
 "0.\n.0\n0.",
 "..\n..\n..",
 ".0\n00\n.0",
 "0.\n.0\n0.",
 "0.\n00\n0.",
 "0.\n0.\n0.",
 "00\n.0\n.."]
```

I need to print the new array onto a file element by element including the correct formatting. i.e.

```
0.0.
00.0
....
```

The issue I am having is it either doesn't format correctly as in just appears as `0.\n00\n..` or puts in one vertical line.

Comment: You can use `.gsub("\n", "")` on each of the strings. But probably there's a way to avoid getting those newlines in there. Could you show that part of the code?

Comment: Tip: Instead of going through all the trouble of typing that syntax out, `'hello world'.chars`

Comment: How are you printing this?

Comment: i ended up trying a different tact, which is working albeit has multiple abstractions to get the data how I need it to run. So my code wouldn't make sense here sadly with this problem statement. I have git commit with it in the old format if it would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write from left to right, you need to *transpose* your output. In order to do so, you have to [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#split-method) each element, [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#transpose-method) the result and [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#join-method) them afterwards:

```
puts braille_converted_message.map(&:split)
                              .transpose
                              .map(&:join)
```

Output:

```
0.0.0.0.0....00.0.0.00
00.00.0..0..00.0000..0
....0.0.0....00.0.0...
```

Note that there's also a Unicode block for [Braille Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_Patterns):

```
⠓⠑⠇⠇⠕⠀⠺⠕⠗⠇⠙
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to output in this form to a text file?

Comment: @JoeyHaas use `f.puts` instead with `f` being your [`File`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/File.html) instance.

Answer (score 0):

One could do the following to minimize memory requirements (i.e., avoiding the construction of temporary arrays) without significantly compromising time-efficiency.

```
File.open('temp', 'w') do |f|
  (braille_converted_message.first.count("\n") + 1).times do |i|
    f.puts braille_converted_message.each_with_object('') do |row,str|
      str << row[3*i,2]
    end
  end
end
```

```
puts File.read('temp')
0.0.0.0.0....00.0.0.00
00.00.0..0..00.0000..0
....0.0.0....00.0.0...
```